# How to install PFSense via PXE

Tags: pfsense, pxe

I was wondering if anyone knew how to install PFSense using a PXE server. I am currently using CentOS 7.4 acting as both the DHCP and PXE server.

What I have tried:

Using Memdisk to load the ISO / IMG files

ISO:
[image: ISO Raw Menu]
[image: Loading ISO Raw]
[image: PFSense Menu]
[image: Mountroot Prompt ISO]

As you can see it does begin to load up PFSense but then gets stuck trying to mount the ISO file. The IMG file variant was mostly the same with the exception of the mount root prompt.

IMG: I tried two combinations here however they both lead to the same prompt. 
[image: IMG Raw Menu]
[image: Loading IMG Raw]
[image: PFSense Menu]
[image: Mountroot Prompt IMG]

Not really sure what else I can try here. I also typed a "?" at the mountroot prompt (to list all valid disks) and unsurprisingly the VMs HDD is shown. However seeing as how it is blank the machine can't boot to it.

[image: Mountroot Question Mark]
[image: Trying to load up ada0]

IMG / ISO 2.3.5 Test Results:

ISO:
[image: Mountroot]

IMG:
[image: 2.3.5 Hang]

If you are wondering why I don't simply insert an ISO into the VMs virtual rom drive I am simulating the physical machine I am attempting to install PFSense to. I am only using virtual machines to make screen grabbing easier.

Here is my pxelinux config file if anyone is curious. 
[image: pxelinux.cfg]

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I added more information on what has been already tried.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Just tested 2.3.5 with fresh files from the pfsense download page (I also verified the hashes on all of the files that are being used they match with the ones on the download page) and while the IMG file did yield a slightly different error the iso stayed the same.

Comment: I haven't tried pfsense on a virtual machine, I always run it on dedicated hardware. What's the hypervisor you are using? I have a copy of VM workstation pro v12. I can try to match your setup if I have some time this week. You have provided enough detail at this point for someone familiar with pfsense on a VM to answer. I'll check back and see if you get an answer, if not I'll try to mirror what you have and see if I can help you get it going.

Comment: Virtualbox. Here is a screenshot of the exact version. https://imgur.com/a/6chAwvw Oracle still hasn't fixed the 5.2.10 version so if you want to run it download it here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_2 Note that I don't think the difference between VBox and VMWare will effect the results.

Answer (score 0):

The answer as of [2017](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/115189/install-pfsense-over-tftp-pxe) seems to be that the installer won't boot using `memdisk` since FreeBSD v9.  It gives these bug reports for more information:

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199197
https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=169919
https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=179312